# cap deploy gives me Capistrano::ConnectionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

```
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname mitosis.example.com: Name or service not known
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

    *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
      * executing "rm -rf /home/httpd/h.example.com/htdocs/www/releases/20131011050831; true"
        servers: ["stagger6.colo.example.com"]
     ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: stagger6.colo.example.com 
          (SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

    Command git ls-remote git@mitosis.example.com:example-site.git master returned status code pid 4571 exit 128
```

Answer (score 0):

The capfile is configured incorrectly.

git@mitosis.example.com:example-site.git is example info.

mitosis.example.com isn't a valid host.